# My ISP connected WAN cable to LAN on my WiFi pouter, and I can't access WiFi router's settings page

Tags: router, internet, wireless-router

As title says, my ISP connected WAN cable that comes from their modem, and according to the modem's settings page, which I can access, Network mode is router and wireless mode is station.

The problem is that I can't access WiFi router's settings page; I can't access login page at all, since 192.168.1.20 is directed to Modem settings, and using `router.asus.com:8443` does nothing, and it fails to connect.

I know my WiFi router is used to transmit WiFi because the modem has no such capability, and the WiFi name and password is one I previously configured on the router.

Basically, it is my router that I bought, and ISP didn't provide it. I configured it and it worked somewhat good, if I remember correctly it had some minor problems as in connection issues and such, but it worked decently. They came to fix it and put WAN cable into LAN, they might've done some changes to the Wifi router settings too. It is now working perfectly, but I do want to change some settings on Wifi router, such as password for my WiFi.

How can I access the WiFi router settings without doing a factory reset on WiFi router, since I'm not sure which, if there are any, settings my ISP changed on it?

Comment: Normally the router should be the one that sets the IP addresses in your Wifi network. So check your computer which IPv4 it had been assigned and change the last number to 1. Most routers assign themselves the 1 as the first IP address in the subnet (assuming the common subnet mask 255.255.255.0 is used).

Comment: The ISP should logically not done anything to a router that doesn't belong to them. To connect to the router, connect it by ethernet to the computer and login directly. The router should be set to repeater/access-point mode with DHCP off, then you may return to the normal setup. Try also with the modem connecting to the WAN port of the router.

Comment: Unfortunately neither work. When I do what Robert mentioned, changing IPv4 last number to 1, I end up with Connection Timeout. When I connect modem to WAN port, as harrymc said, I get no internet connection on my PC, even though LAN cable is connected from the router to my PC. When I do so, other than not having internet connection on my PC, I also can't connect to my WiFi network, even though it is visible. It just keeps on saying "Connecting" and doesn't change from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did manage to open router settings, but I had to do a fabric reset. I did everything and managed to configure it as it was so it worked. As I suspected, it didn't transmit WiFi until I disabled DHCP and put the router to Access-Point mode. Now everything is fine and I managed to find actual IP address Router's Login Page is assigned to.
Thanks to harrymc and Robert for helping me!